# Opaque border color on IOS is not rendered correcly

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I have this style for the `View` component:

```
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  border: 6px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
  border-radius: 100;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

On Android it's rendering as expected but it seems alpha value is not applied on IOS. Rendered results attached below:

Android:

[image]

IOS:

[image]

Can anyone explain this and is there a way to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Turns out it renders border differently on IOS and Android. On IOS, background color is visible through transparent border color. I think this different behaviour should be considered as an issue.

My workaround is to wrap the view with a bigger view and specified its background to transparent one. This works on both IOS and Android, though not elegant.